# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Versions I am using:

- Java 1.8
- Spring Boot v2.7.5

There seems to be [Tomcat] and [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68] trying to start at once, causing an exception, I can't figure out how to solve this.

`mvn install` from pom.xml is successful. Just that there is a runtime exception.

When I run the program:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)


Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]

    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]

    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

    ... 39 more

Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
Dec 29, 2022 12:15:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please share your POM?